# jquery slider of checkbox options and get values

Tags: jquery, filter, checkbox, slider, transform

I have some checkbox options with values and I need to transform it to slider from first value to last value, like a price filter slider. As the slider moves, options that are out of range become unselected. Exactly like the price slider.

This is a product filter on the site. Options are taken from the database of available products.
The "all" option does not participate in the slider, since the entire range is already "all". The "all" option is turned off if it is turned on - "like a slider".

The point is that when the property is turned on with a slider, all checkboxes are hidden. And I need a slider with two handles. It is more necessary to apply this to such product properties as width, depth. So that instead of checkboxes of all centimeters of width there is one neat slider. And the transformation took place according to another checkbox in the property settings, if selected, then the slider. The checkboxes are hidden, the slider remains. As when you filter products by price.

```
<ul class="filter_group sub38" data-feature="38" data-feature_url="memmorysize">
                    
                    <li class="filter_list first">
                        <label class="filter_label">
                            <input class="filter_input cb2" data-feature_url="" type="checkbox" checked="">
                            <span data-language="83">All</span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    
                                            <li class="filter_list">
                            <label class="filter_label">
                                <input class="filter_input cb3" data-option_url="4096" type="checkbox">
                                <span>4096</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                                            <li class="filter_list">
                            <label class="filter_label">
                                <input class="filter_input cb3" data-option_url="8192" type="checkbox">
                                <span>8192</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                                            <li class="filter_list">
                            <label class="filter_label">
                                <input class="filter_input cb3" data-option_url="12288" type="checkbox">
                                <span>12288</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                                            <li class="filter_list">
                            <label class="filter_label">
                                <input class="filter_input cb3" data-option_url="16384" type="checkbox">
                                <span>16384</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                                            <li class="filter_list">
                            <label class="filter_label">
                                <input class="filter_input cb3" data-option_url="32768" type="checkbox">
                                <span>32768</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                                            <li class="filter_list">
                            <label class="filter_label">
                                <input class="filter_input cb3" data-option_url="40960" type="checkbox">
                                <span>40960</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                                                        <div class="show_hide_list sub38" data-feature="38" style="display: none;">Show all</div>
                
                </ul>
```

I have tried to use this - https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/. But, I can't get this to work. Help me, please.

Comment: Should the slider have all increments of 4096 between 4096 and 40960? If so, it looks like `<ul>` is missing some of those values, like 28672.

Comment: I've supplemented to my question. These are the properties of the goods present. They make a filter. But I need to make a slider filter from the minimum value to the maximum. Like a price filter. All checkboxes are hidden. invisible.

Comment: I have voted to close your question because it is unclear to me what you are asking for.

Comment: Everything is clear here!

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to make some assumptions about your objectives. They are:

- You want to display the slider *in addition to* your existing checkboxes.
- The slider will have a minimum value of `4096`, a maximum value of `40960`, and support all increments of `4096` in between - including values for which there is no corresponding checkbox, like `28672`.
- Checking a checkbox will cause the slider handle to move to the checked value.
- Unchecking a checkbox will cause the slider handle to go to the value one increment less than the value of the checked box (this means that the minimum value checkbox, `4096`, cannot be unchecked, since it is the minimum value of the slider).
- Checking the "All" checkbox will cause all value checkboxes to be checked and move the slider handle to the max value.
- Unchecking the "All" checkbox will cause all value checkboxes to be unchecked and move the slider handle to the min value.

As a general note, these are the sort of requirements you will need to clarify as you work on projects and they are the sort of details you need to include in your posts on this site.

```js
$(function () {
  const resetCheckboxes = (event, ui) => {
    const value = ui.value;
    const $slider = $('#Slider');
    const isMaxValue = value === $slider.slider('option', 'max');

    $('[data-option_url]').each(function () {
      const $this = $(this);
      $this.prop('checked', $this.data('option_url') <= value);
    });
    
    $('[data-feature_url=""]').prop('checked', isMaxValue);
  };

  $('#Slider').slider({
    change: resetCheckboxes,
    max: 40960,
    min: 4096,
    slide: resetCheckboxes,
    step: 4096
  });

  $('[data-option_url]').on('change', function () {
    const $this = $(this);
    const thisValue = $this.data('option_url');
    const isChecked = $this.prop('checked');
    const $slider = $('#Slider');
    const value = isChecked ? thisValue : thisValue - $slider.slider('option', 'min');
    const isMaxValue = value === $slider.slider('option', 'max');
    
    $slider.slider('value', value);
    $('[data-feature_url=""]').prop('checked', isMaxValue);
  });

  $('[data-feature_url=""]').on('change', function () {
    const isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
    const $slider = $('#Slider');
    const option = isChecked ? 'max' : 'min';


    $slider.slider('value', $slider.slider('option', option));
  }).trigger('change');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="filter_group sub38" data-feature="38" data-feature_url="memmorysize">

  <li class="filter_list first">
    <label class="filter_label">
      <input class="filter_input cb2" data-feature_url="" type="checkbox" checked="">
      <span data-language="83">All</span>
    </label>
  </li>

  <li class="filter_list">
    <label class="filter_label">
      <input class="filter_input cb3" data-option_url="4096" type="checkbox">
      <span>4096</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="filter_list">
    <label class="filter_label">
      <input class="filter_input cb3" data-option_url="8192" type="checkbox">
      <span>8192</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="filter_list">
    <label class="filter_label">
      <input class="filter_input cb3" data-option_url="12288" type="checkbox">
      <span>12288</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="filter_list">
    <label class="filter_label">
      <input class="filter_input cb3" data-option_url="16384" type="checkbox">
      <span>16384</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="filter_list">
    <label class="filter_label">
      <input class="filter_input cb3" data-option_url="32768" type="checkbox">
      <span>32768</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="filter_list">
    <label class="filter_label">
      <input class="filter_input cb3" data-option_url="40960" type="checkbox">
      <span>40960</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <div class="show_hide_list sub38" data-feature="38" style="display: none;">Show all</div>

</ul>

<div id="Slider"></div>
```